# CORS with Jquery Ajax to Rails API

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, cors, rails-api

I create one sample api in Rails using rails-api gem and enabled the CORS specified [here](https://gist.github.com/dhoelzgen/cd7126b8652229d32eb4)

I tried the api crud operations using 'Advanced Rest API' in chorme and working fine. Now i just added one spa jquery application to the Rails to use the API. I just put my jquery app in the public directory of the Rails API.

My get methods are working correctly but not 'PUT' and 'PATCH'. My client application is in the same app and machine so i think this is not other domain? am i right? Is so i already enabled CORS but not working. I got like 'ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [OPTIONS] "/api/v1/students/1"):'

Please help me to solve this issue..

My client page is

```
<form>
<table role="presentation">
  <tr><td>First name</td> 
  <td>
  <input name="FirstMidName" data-val="true" data-val-required="First name is required" class="form-control">
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="FirstMidName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>Last name</td>  
  <td>
  <input name="LastName" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Last name is required" >
  <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LastName" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
  <td>Enrollment date</td>      
  <td>
    <input name="EnrollmentDate" class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="Enrollment date is required" >
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="EnrollmentDate" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
  </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<input type="hidden" name="id" />
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT" />
<input type="submit" value="update" class="btn btn-default" onclick="return updateData(this)"/>

</form>


<script>
function Success(result){
alert("Data Saved successfully");
window.location.hash="#contact-list";
}

function Failure(err){
alert("Error");
}


function updateData(_this){


$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/students/1",
        type: 'PUT',
        data:$(this).closest('form').serialize(),
        success : function(result){
        alert('done');
        },
        error : function(xhr, txt, err){
        alert(err);
        }

        });

return false;
}

</script>
```

And my base controller is

```
class Api::BaseController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Token'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end

  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == :options
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, Token'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'

      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end
end
```

And my route is

```
namespace :api, :defaults => {:format => :json} do
    namespace :v1 do

      controller :students, path: '/students/:id' do
        match 'post_action', via: [ :post, :options]
      end

      resources :students

    end
  end
```

Comment: Why don't you use [`rack-cors`](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack-cors/versions/0.3.1).

Comment: nothing special. I thought this is simple. I will try that also

Comment: I finished with rack-cors. thanks.. but u that method got erros

Comment: Chech that jquery is sending the correct headers in these request... For example make sure that 'Content-Type' header is set to 'application/json'

Comment: Even now i dont' know why not worked that. But rack-cors solved my issue thanks @albertjan

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I achieved to fix it (without suing rack-cors).
I include my code below:

Filters in application controller:

```
  # Enable CORS
  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers
```

CORS methods:

```
  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method.downcase.to_sym == :options
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end

  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end
```

Then in config/routes.rb...

```
match 'myRoute', to: 'myController#myMethod', via: [:put, :options]
```

and client code...

```
$.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: 'myRoute',
      data: data,
      dataType: "json"
});
```

I think the problem in your code is this:

```
match 'post_action', via: [ :post, :options]
```

Probably chaning :post by :put will fix it.

I'm using Rails '4.2.4'.
I hope it helps.